# Using sum in big dataframe (3.2GB) is very slow

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big data frame (2628x670316) over 3 GB and want to use the sum function on every row.

The data file looks something like this composed of only 0s, 1s and 2s.

```
0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
.
.
.
```

When I run sum(data[1,]==0) this takes ages. Is there a faster way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

PS. The reason I want to use sum is because I want to get the percentage of 0s, 1s and 2s on each row. If there is another way to do that, that answer would also be helpful.

Comment: For a simple row sums you could just use `Reduce("+", data)` it will be both faster and more memory efficient than `rowSums` IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `df` is your data.frame :

```
t(apply(df,1,table))*100/ncol(df)
```

will give you percentages of 0s, 1s and 2s for each row.

(And you avoid making comparisons, which can take a very long time...)

data :

```
set.seed(13)
df<-data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,2),500,T),nrow=10))
```

`t(apply(df,1,table))*100/ncol(df)` gives you :

```
       0  1  2
 [1,] 34 44 22
 [2,] 38 40 22
 [3,] 28 34 38
 [4,] 26 38 36
 [5,] 36 42 22
 [6,] 30 32 38
 [7,] 42 26 32
 [8,] 30 36 34
 [9,] 36 24 40
[10,] 24 34 42
```

EDIT thanks to @akrun 's comment :

In case all possible values (0, 1, 2) are not represented on every row, you have to do :

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=0:2))))*100/ncol(df)
```

Comment: Would be nice if the OP could provide metrics how faster this is

Comment: @akrun : 10 sec for 100x50000

Comment: `system.time(rowSums(!data))#   user  system elapsed 
  0.116   0.007   0.123` on a 100X50000 dataset

Comment: It tried it but got a 'non-numeric argument to binary operator'. Is this an error of my data frame?

Comment: @Javier2013 can you give us a snippet of your data? or a str().

Comment: This is for a smaller data set that is exactly the same as the bigger file: Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 820 obs. of  9852 variables:
 $ V1   : int  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... All variables are integers either 0s, 1s, and 2s, although not every row has all numbers.

Comment: Tried running apply(df,1,table) and it worked! Looks like there is a problem when trying to get percentages from the table.

Comment: @Javier2013, it is weird that you can't get the percentages. Can you show how the output of `apply(df,1,table)` looks like ?

Comment: @Javier2013 Try `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=0:2))))*100/ncol(df)` I was able to get the error using `set.seed(24);
 df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:2, 10*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))`

Comment: thanks @akrun, I edited my answer to take into account data.frames with rows lacking one or more of possible values

Comment: @Javier2013 Testing it on `100x50000` dataset, I got `#user  system elapsed 
 # 2.364   0.000   2.362`

Comment: @Javier2013, you're welcome, I'm happy if I helped you solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the data are all integers, then it's much faster to represent it as a matrix `m` (this is also semantically closer to what the data actually is -- a rectangular collection of data with homogeneous type, rather than of columns of possibly different type), maybe input using `scan()`. With a matrix, column operations are faster than row operations, so transpose it with `t(m)`. The `tabulate()` function is much faster than `table()`, though a little more finicky in the present case

```
nonZeroCounts <- apply(t(m), 2, tabulate, max(m))
```

In more detail, here are proposed solutions

```
f0 <- function(df)
    t(apply(df, 1, table))

f1 <- function(m) {
    n <- t(apply(t(m), 2, tabulate, max(m)))
    ans <- cbind(ncol(m) - as.integer(rowSums(n)), n)
    colnames(ans) <- 0:max(m)
    ans
}
```

some data

```
nrow <- 100; ncol <- floor(nrow * 670316 / 2628)
m <- matrix(sample(0:2, nrow * ncol, TRUE), nrow=nrow)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
```

and basic comparison

```
> system.time(ans0 <- f0(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.082   0.000   1.083 
> system.time(ans1 <- f1(m))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.052   0.000   0.052 
> identical(ans0, ans1)
[1] TRUE
```

or with `nrow=1000`

```
> system.time(ans1 <- f1(m))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.521   1.461   7.984 
> system.time(ans0 <- f0(df))   ## argh, boring, stop after 1.5 minutes!
  C-c C-c
Timing stopped at: 93.608 2.752 96.325
```

Answer (score 0):

try `rowSums`, perhaps it's faster

```
test<-data.frame(V1=c(1,1,1,1), V2=c(2,2,2,0)) 
rowSums(test)
```

I doubt however you can get faster sum functions than the vanilla sum.

Another way to get the sums is the notorious [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) function family

```
apply(test, 1, sum)
```

Did some tests and `rowSums` is quite fast

```
set.seed(13)
df<-data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,2),500000000,T),nrow=2000))
system.time(rowSums(df))

system.time(rowSums(df))
   user  system elapsed 
   8.00    0.68    8.69
```

Whereas for `apply`

```
system.time(apply(df, 1, sum))


   user  system elapsed 
  81.67    5.99   87.96
```

Comment: Doesn't rowSums creates a matrix, that is copying first 3GB of data?

Comment: probably. OP was unclear what his final intention was until the last edit of the question

Comment: @Javier2013 it does not seem that rowSums does any copying since data creation takes more time than rowSums. I was suprized too. Perhaps a more knowledgable member can give us some feedback.

Comment: @ECII It would be better to also include the comparisons between `t(apply(df,1,table))*100/ncol(df)` and the equivalent using `rowSums`

Comment: @Javier2013 `apply` first coerces a `data.frame` to a matrix too!